# Error 'is_empty' was not declared in this scope.why does it give error?

Tags: c

output=[Error] 'is_empty' was not declared in this scope
must be:
Example
Input string : abbccba*abccbba message will be The string is valid
aaabbcb*bcbaab message will be The string is invalid
aadbxcy*ycxbdaa message will be Wrong character!!!
what should i do?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{
 char home[35];
 int top;
} My_stack;

void push(My_stack * s, char c) // push (insert) operation
{ // assume there is enough space for pushing next element!
    s -> top ++;
    s -> home[s -> top] = c;
}

int pop(My_stack * s) // pop (remove) operation
{
    if(is_empty (*s)) {
        printf("ERROR: Nothing to pop - program terminates\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return (s ->home[s ->top --]);
}

int is_empty(My_stack * s) // checking whether stack is empty or not
{
    return(s -> top < 0 ? 1 : 0);
}
    
int main(){
    char ch[25];
    int i,l;
    My_stack stack;
    printf("give the string");
    scanf("%s",ch);
    l=strlen(ch);
    i=0;    
    while(ch[i]!='\0') {
        if(ch[i]!='A'&&ch[i]!='B'&& ch[i]!='*') {
            printf("the string is not accepted allowed caracters are A,B and * ");
            exit(0);
        }
        i++;
    }   
    i=0;    
    while(ch[i] != '*') {
        push(&stack, ch[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i++; // one step forward to pass '*
    while(ch[i] != '\0') {
        if(ch[i] != pop(&stack)) {
            printf("the string is not valid");
            exit(0);
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("the string is valid");          
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The C compiler reads from top to bottom. Put a declaration for `is_empty` above its point of first use, or move the definition up above its point of first use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, you need to pass the pointer to the function, not the actual value, so your functioncall must be changed to:

```
is_empty (s)
```

instead of

```
is_empty (*s)
```

Then, the reason is because you define your function `is_empty` after your first use. To prevent this error, you should *declare* your function first. This tells the compiler "hey, there exists this function with this signature, the definition is given later though" so then you can use it in your program before having implemented it explicitly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{
 char home[35];
 int top;
} My_stack;

int is_empty(My_stack * s); // <----- DECLARATION OF FUNCTION

int pop(My_stack * s) // pop (remove) operation
{
    if(is_empty (s)) {
        printf("ERROR: Nothing to pop - program terminates\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return (s ->home[s ->top --]);
}

int is_empty(My_stack * s) // checking whether stack is empty or not
{
    return(s -> top < 0 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Or, you put the entire definition before your first use so then there's no need for a declaration:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{
 char home[35];
 int top;
} My_stack;

int is_empty(My_stack * s) // checking whether stack is empty or not
{
    return(s -> top < 0 ? 1 : 0);
}

int pop(My_stack * s) // pop (remove) operation
{
    if(is_empty (s)) {
        printf("ERROR: Nothing to pop - program terminates\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return (s ->home[s ->top --]);
}
```